# How to applying css style into an iframe content?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to apply a CSS style for content inside the iframe, please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/pPqGe/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('h1').css('color','red');
});
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="mysite" width="100%" height="100%" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

For iframe source I have used a live website.

Comment: You can pass them as query string to the iframed page.

Comment: shnisaka is right, it's just not possible otherwise. Browsers come with that restriction for security reasons, it's called "cross-domain scripting".

Comment: If you are calling in another web page that lives on your same domain, then simply use ajax to call that page content.

Answer (score 7):

It works. Problem is there is no H1, only H2.
Check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/pPqGe/1545/.

HTML:

```
<iframe src='jsfiddle.net'></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('h2').css('color','red');
    $('iframe').contents().find('#header').css('opacity','.2');
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right.It's working fine in jsfiddle, but i am using another source file for iframe.                                    **For example:**"<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('.headline').css('color','red');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>" it's not support. _.headline_ class is available on smashingmagazine but it would not affected.