# Cant style Facebook share button as its in an iframe?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-iframe

Is it possible to use CSS to style the facebook share button? The problem im having is that the javascript creates an iframe meaning normal CSS on the page doenst affect the styling of the iframe.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Facebook Do's and Don'ts](https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts), you are not allowed to

> Modify Facebook brand assets in any way, such as by changing the design or color

So I guess that settles the matter.

Should you really want to customize the content of an `iframe`, the question has already been asked multiple times: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe), or [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316562/style-content-within-an-iframe) or even [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812946/how-to-applying-css-style-into-an-iframe-content).